# How to create a user provided redis service which spring auto configuration cloud connectors picks?

Tags: redis, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have created a user provided service for redis as below

```
cf cups p-redis -p "{\"host\":\"xx.xx.xxx.xxx\",\"password\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"port\":6379}"
```

This not getting picked automcatically by the redis auto reconfiguration or the service connectors and getting jedis connection pool exception.

When I bind to the redis service created from the market place it works fine with the spring boot application. This confirms there is no issue with the code or configuration. I wanted a custom service for the redis to work with the spring boot app. How can i create such service? What am i missing here? Is this possible?

```
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "user-provided": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "host": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
     "password": "xxxxxxxx",
     "port": 6379
    },
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "p-redis",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": []
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

I could extend the abstract cloud connector and create redis factory myself but i want to make it work out of the box with custom service and auto configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All routes to mapping this service automatically lead to the [`spring-cloud-connectors` project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors).  If you look at the implementation, services must be either [tagged with `redis`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/cloudfoundry/RedisServiceInfoCreator.java#L16) or [expose a uri with a `redis` scheme](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/service/common/RedisServiceInfo.java#L14) from [credential keys based on a permutation of `uri`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator.java#L82-L94).

If you'd like additional detection behavior, I'd recommend [opening an issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/issues) in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. URI scheme worked. 'redis://:e19ca42d-7b6b-4fcc-9735-b5570d5a9df2@10.106.124.172:6379'. Tags is not an option atleast for now as it is not supported for user provided services.

Comment: Tags can currently (in 2019) be added to the `cf cups` command via the `-t` parameter. I recently set up a user-defined redis connection with `cf cups p-redis -p "{\"host\":\"xx.xx.xxx.xxx\",\"password\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"port\":6379}" -t "redis"`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
cf cups redis -p '{"uri":"redis://:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME:PORT"}' -t "redis"
```

Thanks to earlier answers that led me to this solution.

Comment: why add the date in your answer? It is shown there above your usercard.